# How do you acquire more Pharros Lockstones if you have already used all of them?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Pharros lockstones allow you to open certain areas and manipulate certain contraptions in the game. Merchants sell a limited amount of these items yet they are integral in progressing through the storyline. There are far more Pharros Contraptions than there are lockstones and using them will destroy them.

How can I acquire more lockstones if I have already bought the ones the merchants sell and used them?

Comment: Sounds like a dark souls trap if I have ever heard one before lol just like if you didnt kill a specific person in demon souls then that person killed the whole main village thing and you couldn't level up until the next play through haha

Comment: The first death unlocks an achievement 'This is Dark Souls'. I died before I even got to character creation screen.

Comment: Yup that seems about right, I'll have to pick this game up soon. Good luck, hope someone can help you!

Comment: I highly doubt you're at the end of the game, and even if you are are you certain you've explored everywhere? Are you *sure* that you've found all the lockstones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In either Doors of Pharros or the well down Majula, if you're summoned as a gray phantom and win, you're awarded with one, so they're pretty easy to farm, since you get summoned super easily in those areas

Comment: Do you know what covenant that is?

Comment: Rat Covenant...